# RxJS observable does not trigger subscribe after mergeMap

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, signalr

I'm trying to group my collection of data using the RxJS operators and split it in multiple streams in my Angular app, but cannot seem to get it to work. In my `SignalRService` I'm setting up a SignalR trigger in the constructor, such that when data is passed from the server, it will pass it to the Subject I created.

```
export class SignalRService {
  private connection?: signalR.HubConnection;
  private orders = new Subject<OrderModel[]>();
  orders$ = this.orders.asObservable();
    
  constructor() {
    // ... SignalR connection functions ...
    
    this.connection?.on('GetOrders', (data: OrderModel[]) => {
      this.orders.next(data);
    });
  }
};
```

In the `OrderService` I subscribe to the `orders$` Subject by using some pipe operators, because I want to split the data in 3 different streams based on the `status` of the `Order` object.

I flatten the map, use groupBy and then merge again using the key and corresponding data, however, this does not work for some reason and I'm not sure where I should look.
When I use the `tap` operators in between the current operators, it only logs the first two taps. It never seems to get to the third and thus never executes the subscribe I suppose.
Also, when `this.orders.next(data)` in `SignalRService` gets executed twice or more, nothing happens.

```
export class OrderService {
  // Observable sources
  private orderCategory0 = new BehaviorSubject<OrderModel[]>([]);
  private orderCategory1 = new BehaviorSubject<OrderModel[]>([]);
  private orderCategory2 = new BehaviorSubject<OrderModel[]>([]);
  private orders = [this.orderCategory0, this.orderCategory1, this.orderCategory2];
  // Observable streams
  orderCategory0$ = this.orderCategory0.asObservable();
  orderCategory1$ = this.orderCategory1.asObservable();
  orderCategory2$ = this.orderCategory2.asObservable();
  
  constructor(private signalRService: SignalRService) {
    signalRService.orders$
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((res) => res),
        //tap((res) => console.log(res)), <-- This one shows
        groupBy((order: OrderModel) => order.status),
        //tap((res) => console.log(res)), <-- This one shows
        mergeMap((group) => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
        //tap((res) => console.log(res)), <-- This one doesn't
      )
      .subscribe(([groupId, data]) => this.orders[groupId].next(data));
  }
};
```

Note that when I do something like the following in `OrderService`, everything works as expected:

```
signalRService.orders$.subscribe((data: OrderModel[]) => {
  const groups = this.groupData(data);

  this.orderCategory0.next(groups[0]);
  this.orderCategory1.next(groups[1]);
  this.orderCategory2.next(groups[2]);
});
```

Currently, I'm lost, maybe I'm doing this completely wrong, so any pointers would be appreciated.

**Edit**: Also, when I hardcode the Orders and use `of(orders).pipe(...).subscribe(...)`, and thus omit the `signalRService.order$`-part, everything works fine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `group.pipe(toArray())` is never going to emit, because **group** is an observable that stays open (presumably until **order$** completes), and **toArray** waits to emit until the observable completes.  That being said, the use of **groupBy** was probably overkill to begin with.

If I interpret you example correctly, you're creating the groups just to pass them off to the correct behavior subject which are in a collection keyed by status.  You can just use array.reduce (or Ramda's groupBy) to create groups, no need to convert the array to an observable if you don't really need the stream.

```
signalRService.orders$.subscribe((orders: OrderModel[]) => {
  const groups = orders.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      (acc[cur.status] || (acc[cur.status] = [])).push(cur);
      return acc;
    },
    {} as Record<string, OrderModel[]>);
  Object.values(entries).forEach(([k, v]) => this.orders[k].next(order);
});
```

*If* you really need the **groupBy** (maybe this is a simplification of a bigger problem), then don't use **zip** and have an inner pipe instead.

You probably don't need the subjects either.  You can map orders to the grouped object and then project the individual groups as needed.

```
const readonly orders$ = signalRService.orders$.pipe(
  map((orders) => orders.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      (acc[cur.status] || (acc[cur.status] = [])).push(cur);
      return acc;
    },
    {} as Record<string, OrderModel[]>)
  ),
  shareReplay(1)
);
const readonly orderCategory0$ = this.orders$.pipe(map(x => x['status0'] || []));
const readonly orderCategory1$ = this.orders$.pipe(map(x => x['status1'] || []));
const readonly orderCategory2$ = this.orders$.pipe(map(x => x['status2'] || []));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it out tomorrow and I'll come back to you :) looks promising

Comment: Well, I need the arrays of grouped values so I can display them in their own component using `ngFor` with the `async` pipe. Correct me if I'm wrong, but what this solution gives me is a stream of objects instead of object arrays. Any idea to map the entries to an array? I'm aware `toArray()` exists, but I'd have to define a `takeX`, which is not ideal because it completes the stream, correct? I'm new to RxJS, so any suggestion is helpful :)

Comment: Are you accumulating the results?  That is, every time a new entry is added the array for that group gets larger?  In that case you'd use `scan((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], [])`.

Comment: The `data` in `orders.next(data)` is continuously 'refreshing'. Every n seconds, the server pushes a fresh, updated list of orders. This list should replace the current lists that are being displayed. Plural, because there are 3 tables being displayed (`orderCategoryX`), each containing the orders based on their `status`.

Comment: Oh wait.  that mergeMap res, you were just converting the array to an observable?  I thought that was strange and that somehow it was another observable..

Comment: Thanks for your help, that did the trick! For other people seeing these comments: the answer has been adjusted, so some comments do not apply to the answer anymore.